# Delete Last Row in a Table - SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have the following basic SQL query:

```
DELETE TOP (1)
FROM dbo.userPasswordHistory
WHERE UserId IN (SELECT Id FROM dbo.user WHERE LogonId = @UserLogonId)
```

I want to delete the most recent entry in the `dbo.userPasswordHistory` table but `DELETE TOP (1)` is deleting the oldest entry, not the most recent. So for instance if the `dbo.userPasswordHistory` table contains 5 rows for a specified user then it is the most recent entry that I want to delete.

How would I order the table based on a column called `LastModifiedTime` or is there a way I can specify bottom or last?

Comment: include proper tag. Top is not mysql keyword. is your query from mysql or sql server and update your question with sample data and desired result set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a subquery or CTE:

```
DELETE t
FROM (SELECT TOP (1) uph.*
      FROM dbo.userPasswordHistory uph
      WHERE UserId IN (SELECT Id
                       FROM dbo.user
                       WHERE LogonId = @UserLogonId
                      )
      ORDER BY LastModifiedTime DESC
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I am looking for. However, what does the 't' denote? I know it is needed as without the statement doesn't execute.

Comment: @bez91 . . . The `t` is a table alias.  SQL Server requires table aliases for subqueries in the `from` clause.